# What is the difference between `brew` and `brew cask`?

Tags: command-line, homebrew

So, what is the difference between `brew` and `brew cask`?

I know that homebrew is a package management software. But what kind of software can I get there? Is it open source software and commercial software?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403937/what-is-the-difference-between-brew-install-xxx-and-brew-cask-install-xxx

Comment: As of Homebrew 2.6.0 `brew cask` has been deprecated in favor of `brew`: https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/

Comment: I think the above comment about brew cask deprecation is slightly misleading as most `brew cask` commands now use `brew` with `--cask` (also hinted at in the linked blog post). See @Epic Programmer's answer for further detail: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/449692/175188

Answer (score 459, accepted):

### Homebrew

`brew` is the core command for the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) project.

> The missing package manager for OS X
>
> Homebrew installs the stuff you need that Apple didn’t.

Homebrew typically deals with command line software. Most of the software is distributed under an open source licence. See the [Formulas](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/) for a list of available installs.

`brew` [*prefers* pre-compiled binaries](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-do-you-compile-everything) but will compile from source in some cases.

### Cask

`brew cask` is an extension to `brew` that allows management of graphical applications through the [Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask) project.

> Homebrew Cask extends Homebrew and brings its elegance, simplicity,
> and speed to OS X applications and large binaries alike.

Cask deals with a mixture of software and licences. The software I work on is covered by a commercial licence and [available via cask](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2014-01-21-dssw-available-via-homebrew-cask/).

Cask offers a way to command line manage the installation of graphical applications.

See `brew cask` issue [#7002](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/7002) about the project's focus on predictability and how that affects the use of pre-compiled binaries or source.

### Licensing

Availability through `brew` or `cask` does not imply any specific licence.

Comment: Thank you for this explicit answer. In short, `brew` is for command-line softwares while `brew cask` is for graphical softwares.

Comment: On the [MS Website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos?view=powershell-7.2) `cask` is used. Why, if `pwsh` is not a guy?

Comment: @Timo `cask` is not limited to GUI based applications. Why Microsoft chose `cask` is a question only answerable by Microsoft.

Comment: The reason is precompilled only vs source-available software

Answer (score 28):

`brew cask install foo` appears to be a shortcut for `brew install caskroom/cask/foo`:

```
ct@MBA45:~$ brew tap
caskroom/cask
homebrew/core
homebrew/php
ct@MBA45:~$ brew install meld
Error: No available formula with the name "meld" 
It was migrated from homebrew/core to caskroom/cask.
You can access it again by running:
  brew tap caskroom/cask
ct@MBA45:~$ brew tap caskroom/cask
ct@MBA45:~$ brew install meld
Error: No available formula with the name "meld" 
It was migrated from homebrew/core to caskroom/cask.
You can access it again by running:
  brew tap caskroom/cask
ct@MBA45:~$ brew install caskroom/cask/meld
==> brew cask install caskroom/cask/meld 
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://github.com/yousseb/meld/releases/download/osx-9/meldmerge.dmg
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> Verifying checksum for Cask meld
==> Installing Cask meld
==> Moving App 'Meld.app' to '/Applications/Meld.app'.
==> Linking Binary 'Meld' to '/usr/local/bin/meld'.
  meld was successfully installed!
ct@MBA45:~$ brew cask install meld
Warning: Cask 'meld' is already installed.

To re-install meld, run:
  brew cask reinstall meld
```

[Cask is the part of brew for GUI apps.](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/why-is-homebrew-cask-not-the-preferred-method-to-install-gui-apps.2025887/)

Answer (score 22):

In 2021, `brew cask` was removed. Most of all the old `brew cask` commands have a `--cask` modifier for the commands. For example, `brew cask install` is now `brew install --cask`, `brew cask uninstall` is `brew uninstall --cask`, and so on.