# What's the difference between `brew tap caskroom/cask` and `brew install brew-cask`?

Tags: macos, homebrew

There seem to be different ways to do similar(?) things:

- `brew tap caskroom/cask`
- `brew install brew-cask`
- and even `brew cask` alone does something on a fresh install

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Homebrew is [written in Ruby](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tree/master/Library/Homebrew), which uses Perl's motto of ["There's more than one way to do it"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) to [cater to every special interest](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/520619), to the [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401361/in-ruby-theres-more-than-one-way-of-doing-the-same-thing-what-does-this-mea) of [newbies](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125468/what-is-the-difference-between-brew-and-brew-cask/293040).

[bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike) thinks this is important:

> Also - the handling of taps / casks has changed over time. On Homebrew
>   1.2.4 you can jump straight to installing from cask and the best guide on getting started that's current is:
>
> - https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md

But it confuses me as [`brew install caskroom/cask/foo` does the same as `brew cask install foo`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/293040/20817).